# BST tree- running time

Tags: performance, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have a pseudo- code:

```
function func(BST t):
    x = MIN(t)
    for i=1..n do:
        print x.key
        x = SUCCESSOR(x)
```

Now, I need to prove it's runnig time is THETA(n).
BUT, I know SUCCESSOR running time is O(logn), and therefor running time is O(nlogn).
where is my mistake here?

Thank in advance...

Comment: Where does `n` come from, is it related to anything of `t`?

Comment: n= number of nodes in BST t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- This not true, the run time is `O(nlogn)`
- You know the **exact** implementation of SUCCESSOR, which has upper bounded logarithmic complexity (as stated, `O(logn)`), but you can deduce, that when performing it one after another it actually degenerates to `theta(1)`. In fact, good implementation of SUCCESSOR in BST should have amortized `theta(1)` complexity as each node will be visited **at most twice** during the whole `func` execution.

Answer (score 0):

**It really depends** on the implementation of your BST, but if your BST holds a 'father' node, and is using it to find the successor, **it will need to traverse each edge at most twice** - once one you go "down", the first time to the node, and one when you go "up", back from it.

Since a tree has `n-1` edges, you get at **most `2*(n-1)`** number edges read, and this is **`O(n)`**.

Note that indeed the worst case of the `SUCCESSOR()` function is `O(logn)`, but the average case is `O(1)`, if it is implemented the way I described.